# AG-GRID Angular filter using cellRenderer with complex data

Tags: ag-grid

I am using cellRenderer property, I am able to display the data in the table however I am using an if statement to change the value of the data. Here is what I have in my cellRenderer property:

```
cellRenderer:function (params){
if(params.data.valueofdata === 1){
   return 'the value is one';
}else if(params.data.valueofdata === 2){
   return 'the value is two';
} else {
   return '';
}
```

the display in the tables are correct, however when i use the floating filter or the default filter, it will not filter according to the correct value that I have inputted. however if i search 1 or 2 it will display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here try this.

```
valueGetter: function (params) {
                if (params.data.identity === 1) {
                    return 'Serialised';
                } else if (params.data.identity === 2) {
                    return 'Batched';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },
```

I just changed the values from cellRenderer to valueGetter

Answer (score 2):

`cellRenderer` is just to render the cell content. While filter works with the values in the data bound to the grid.

Use `valueGetter` or `valueFormatter` for this.

Refer below documentation for better understanding:
1. [Value Getter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#value-getter)
2. [Value Formatter vs Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#value-formatter-vs-cell-renderer)

> cellRenderer's are for when you want to include HTML markup and potentially functionality to the cell. So for example, if you want to put punctuation into a value, use a valueFormatter, if you want to put buttons or HTML links use a cellRenderer. It is possible to use a combination of both, in which case the result of the valueFormatter will be passed to the cellRenderer.